# Mergesort with a half-sized help vector

Tags: c++, mergesort

I've been trying to optimize a mergesort implementation by using a help vector that is only half the size of the vector that needs to be sorted. It should be possible, but I don't see it.
The normal merge uses a full sized help vector, has 2 iterators on the original vector, one starting at the left site and one just at (or past if the vector has an even size) the middle.

Full sized help vector merge

```
void TDMergeSort<T>::merge(vector<T>& v, int links, int midden, int rechts, vector<T>& hulp) const{
        int j = links;
        int li = links;
        int ri = midden;
        while (li < midden && ri < rechts) {
            if (v[li] < v[ri]) {
                hulp[j++] = v[li++];
            } else {
                hulp[j++] = v[ri++];
            }
        }

        while (li < midden) {
            hulp[j++]=v[li++];
        }
        while (ri < rechts) {
            hulp[j++]=v[ri++];
        }
    for(int i=links;i<rechts;i++){
        v[i]=move(hulp[i]);
    }
}
```

How can you convert this to a version where hulp is not v.size(), but v.size()/2?

Comment: The help vector needs to be (v.size+1)/2 (round up if an odd number of elements). The two halves of the original vector are sorted, next the first half is moved to the help vector, then the help vector and second half of the original vector are merged back into the original vector starting at the beginning of the original vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once I used a similar approach to solve a HackerRank problem (see below for the adaptation to your approach):

```
void merge(std::vector<int>& original, long long left, long long middle, const long long end) {
    const std::vector<int> leftSide({original.begin()+left, original.begin()+middle});
    const std::vector<int>& rightSide=original; // just to make the code clearer
    auto posForward=left;
    auto right=middle;
    // reset left offsets because we are using a new collection
    middle -= left, left = 0;
    for ( ; left < middle && right < end; ++posForward) {
        if (leftSide[left] <= rightSide[right]) {
            original[posForward] = leftSide[left++];
        } else {
            original[posForward] = rightSide[right++];
            // inversions += (middle-left); // info: removed for this SO answer
        }
    }
    while (left < middle) {
        original[posForward++] = leftSide[left++];
    }
    while (right < end) {
        original[posForward++] = rightSide[right++];
    }
}
```

You can see a full program [here](https://github.com/whoan/challenges/blob/master/hacker-rank/cracking-the-code-interview/counting-inversions.cpp)

---

#### Code adapted to your needs:

```
void TDMergeSort<T>::merge(vector<T>& v, int links, int midden, int rechts, vector<T>& hulp) const {
    hulp = {v.begin()+links, v.begin()+midden};
    int j = links;
    int ri = midden;
    midden -= links;
    int li = 0;

    while (li < midden && ri < rechts) {        
        if (hulp[li] <= v[ri]) {
            v[j++] = hulp[li++];
        } else {
            v[j++] = v[ri++];
        }
    }

    while (li < midden) {
        v[j++]=hulp[li++];
    }
    while (ri < rechts) {
        v[j++]=v[ri++];
    }
}
```